# When should a GWT widgetSet need to be recompiled?

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin

In a GWT hello world example, if I compile and run the app, the widgetSet obviously gets compiled as this has never been done.

If I change the label in my hello world app to say "Hello World 2", should the widget set need to be recompiled?

I am using maven and do have a stub widgetSet defined in the project which inherits a couple of other widgetSets. I am using Vaadin but I think this a generic GWT issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the contents of label will trigger a full recompile of your GWT application. The GWT compiler is monolithic - it requires a full view of every part of the source because it performs many optimizations over the entirety of your application. Because of this any change in any part of the application will require a full compile.

[Developer Mode](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideDevMode) will allow you to see changes more quickly than by recompiling and redeploying your application.

Comment: I you have a Vaadin component which takes "Hello world" as parameter, then the widgetset should not have to be recompiled after each change. But if you change the value of the label in your GWT widget itself, then Jason's answer should apply.